# Get value from one field, and paste it in to a new column

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, copy, vba

I'm relatively new to Microsoft Access, and just a beginner with SQL programming.

I have a table in MS Access. It is an import from a .txt file. In the first column There is a String with a Number or Code in it. This number always Comes after a string "Arbeitslpatz "(The first character starts at string Position 17) and always changes every 76 rows. (Total rows 29790). What I want to achieve is to copy this number (for example 101100) and paste it in a new column in the first 76 rows. Then comes the next number for the next 76 rows, and so on. (I later want to to a lookup function with SQL WHERE functions and return some desired values, and for that I need to have these "Arbeitsplatz numbers" in a new row. 
I already assigned an ID to the file, but I didn't manage to get farther. (I experimented with VBA Loops, but didn' really succeed)
Either SQL or VBA Code would be appreciated.
[image]

[image]

I don't know how well the screenshots can be seen &/ if I provided enough Information...

Thank you all for your help

This is an Image from the orignial text file which I linkt to the database in Access:

[image]

Comment: Process your text file, perform needed action using common VBA functions, save this file back, then import (or insert data into table line-by-line during parsing loop - I think it is easiest).

Comment: I Need to update this file daily. And saddly my VBA Knowledge is as Basic as it can be. Could you by any Chance provide a sample Code, or Concept that would give me at least an idea or a starting Point? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Replace your source data picture with source text file sample (decrease 76 lines to 2 or 3, give 2 such data blocks - it's enough). Additionally you may share the whole file using some online service (https://pastebin.com/ for example).

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the text file

Comment: If You like pictures so much, why aren't You a photographer?

Comment: Actuallly I am a hobby photographer :) This is a link to the first three tables in my text file https://file.io/Ex9RVA

Comment: Maybe this link is better https://filebin.net/lh49jxjaevt4jgn1/uDmiZXaS.txt?t=5271t4bu

Comment: @Akina I'm sorry to bother you… Could you please check my Code? I really Need to find a sollution fast... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited OP code:

```vba
Function Macro1()
'' dim variables
Dim tmp As String, temp() As String
Dim rs As Recordset
'' open source for reading
Open "J:\80_Applications\SAPGuiScripting\01_TXT_Files\CM01_Total.csv" For Input As #1
'' attach recordset to table
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("CM01_Total_1") 
'' loop source - read line-by-line until its end
Do Until EOF(1)
  '' read one line
  Line Input #1, tmp
  '' look if it is a header, if yes, extract and store the number
  If Left(tmp, 12) = "Arbeitsplatz" Then num = Trim(Mid(tmp, 17,8))
  '' look if it is a data line
  If InStr(tmp, "|") > 0 And InStr(tmp, "Woche") = 0 Then
    '' divide the line to separate fields
    temp = Split(tmp, "|")
    With rs
      '' add new, empty, record
      .AddNew
      '' set values into fields
      !Arbeitsplatz = num
      !Woche = temp(1)
      !Bedarf = temp(2)
      !Angebot = temp(3)
      !Belast = temp(4)
      ![freie_Kap] = temp(5)
      !Einh = temp(6)
      '' save editions
      .Update
    End With
  End If
'' loop to reading the next line
Loop
'' close source file and recordset
Close #1
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

PS. Error handler must be added.

Comment: @Neymar0001 Comments added.

Answer (score 0):

This code runs without an error, but doesn't do anything...

Option Compare Database

```
Function Macro1()
Dim tmp As String, temp() As String
Dim rs As Recordset
Open "J:\80_Applications\SAPGuiScripting\01_TXT_Files\CM01_Total_1.txt" For Input As #1
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("CM01_Total_1")
Do Until EOF(1)
  Line Input #1, tmp
  If Left(tmp, 12) = "Arbeitsplatz" Then num = Val(Mid(tmp, 17))
  If InStr(tmp, "|") > 0 And InStr(tmp, "Woche") = 0 Then
    temp = Split(tmp, "|")
    With rs
      .AddNew
      !Arbeitsplatz = num
      !Woche = temp(1)
      !Bedarf = temp(2)
      !Angebot = temp(3)
      !Belast = temp(4)
      ![freie Kap] = temp(5)
      !Einh = temp(6)
      .Update
    End With
  End If
Loop
Close #1
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: *The newest error essage is: Runtime error '424'. Object required.* You must `dim rs as recordset`, open your destination table in it before the cycle and close after. And I'd recommend to define all variables as local for your macro.

Comment: My answer is now altered according to your code.

Comment: @Akina Thank you SOOOOOOO much for your help! Now the Code runs without Errors, but doesn't do any modifications in my table… What am I doing wrong? (The Problem is that I don't understand what part of the Code does what, and I'm completely lost in it...)

Comment: *but doesn't do any modifications in my table* It must insert new records, not modify existing ones. *I don't understand what part of the Code does what* I'll comment it a little. wait...

Comment: You are a Genious!!! I don't know how can I thank you! It worked!! Thanks a 1 000 000!!